# How to ask for the specific time and place of an interview?

Tags: interviewing

I just got my first interview offer for an internship at a company. They told me that the interview will be in the afternoon and will be held in their headquarter, but they didn't tell me the specific time and the address of their HQ.

Is it ok for me to ask where and when to attend to the interview? And if so, how should I phrase my request for clarification?

Comment: Who is "they"? Yes, you should just ask. Be polite and request the information.

Comment: They is the interviewer, so actually we already have the interview, but its not the formal interview, because I have interview with 4 other peoples. And the person who contacted me is the person who interview me last time. Sorry my English is not really good. And could you give me example? Thank you

Comment: When is the interview? If it's a week from now, just wait a little bit. Someone from HR should contact you. Those things just take time to set up. Now, if the interview is this week, by all means, ask them now.

Comment: For clarification: Where is the company based? If in the US or one of the EU countries it shouldn't be hard to find out their HQ-address via offcial and public business-registers.. Or maybe their website? In regards to the vague time they provided - just ask them a couple of days before the interview (in case they haven't contacted you already) for the exact time..

Comment: Be sure to find out exactly where you need to go. Knowing the address of their headquarters doesn't necessarily tell you which entrance to use (speaking from experience).

Answer (score 12):

**Reply to the invite and ask.**

Something like this will do:

> Hey [insert name of contact],
>
> Can I get the specifics for the interview please? Is [insert address you found on Google so you show some research effort] the correct address? And what time should I be there for?
>
> Thanks,
>
> Julia

Modify appropriately if you have been communicating more formally.

Comment: I agree with asking for a specific time in case they were vague, but wouldn't asking for the address/clarifying come across as unprofessional -  considering the fact that OP applied for an internship at a company and doesn't know/can't find out herself where the HQ is? Any official business registers/listings of the country in question will have their HQ-address if it's a legit company (except charlies chocolate factory in umpa-lumpa land).

Comment: @iLuvLogix For the UK at least the listed address in google etc may include the 'wrong' postcode due to there being a specific postcode for the building but the company may have a different postcode which directs all mail to what is in effect a PO box - Mail sent to this postcode is delivered separately to the 'normal' postal deliveries but can be in a totally different place when you program it into your Sat Nav. - At one company I used to work we were always getting calls from people who couldn't find us because the postcode they had used took them to a location several miles away. ...cont

Comment: In fact this was a single 10 story building where there was a postcode for the building itself (which was the 'proper postcode' but then each wing of each floor had its own postcode  -  This meant that the postal service sorted the mail by postcode and it meant fewer staff required in the building mailroom to sort the post for the different floors.

If you looked up the company in any PUBLICLY available directory you would not find the actual building postcode listed, This resulted in 'Sat nav instructions' being sent with every meeting invite.

Comment: @EdHunter I'm not talking about googling it ;) What I meant were official biz-registers from the gov, such as https://www.gov.uk/get-information-about-a-company for example.. Otherwise the impressum or contact page of their website would be a good place to start with..

Comment: @iLuvLogix one could argue it's rather unprofessional for the recruiter to not communicate the specific time and address when scheduling the interview, and since they haven't done it in this case I don't think there's anything wrong with clarifying these details.

Comment: @iLuvLogix There's nothing wrong with double checking that the address you've found is where they expect you to be for the interview. Loads of companies have offices in multiple buildings, for example. It's not inappropriate to clarify, and it could cost the job not to.

Comment: @EdHunter One place I worked at had the instructions "Follow your SatNav. At the very last roundabout, take the third exit, not the fourth as your SatNav tells you".

Answer (score 1):

You can't assume anything about the interview. Saying that it is at headquarters isn't helpful because some companies don't have a single HQ.

The person you have been in contact with should be the one to provide the exact time and location.

They should also provide any other relevant information such as: park in the visitor lot, go in the East entrance , and stop by the receptionist on the 2nd floor. They may even have a document to send you that includes a map, GPS coordinates, and nearest subway station.

They may give you alternate numbers to call if you are running late, or if you have any issues on the day of the interview.

I would send a quick email reply:

> Mrs Smith,
>
> I look forward to the interview on the xth of January.
>
> What time should I arrive at the interview location so that I can take
> care of any entrance procedures, or to complete any paperwork?
>
> I understand it is to be held at your headquarters building, but I
> have never been there. Can you please send me the address of the
> building and the room number. Is there is any other information such
> as parking that I need to know before I arrive?
>
> I look forward to your reply.
>
> Sincerely,
> Julia

Answer (score 0):

You get the company's phone number and dial it. That should connect you to their reception. Then you tell them that you have an interview and on which day, for what position or with which person would be helpful, and you ask them what the exact time and place is for the interview.

Plan for taking a bit longer to that place. I had one interview where I ended up about 10 meters away from the main entrance of the building - unfortunately separated by a fence, and it took a few minutes to walk all around the building to the main entrance. Another interview was in January, and half the town where the interview was was closed down because of snow and ice. Including the street that I was taking. That was about a 2 miles detour by car.